# Filling multiple vector with random numbers

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

The goal here is to create a vector of vectors, each holding a different sized vector, those being 100, 200, 400, 800, 1600 , 3200, 6400, and 12800. Here is my code for that:

```
void vectorGenerator() {
    int i;
    vector<int> vectorList;

    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        vector<int> temp(100*pow(2,i));
        for (unsigned int l = 0; l<temp.size(); l++)
            temp(l) = (rand() % 20000);
        vectorList.push_back(temp);
    }
```

The error I am getting is coming from the line:

```
temp(l) = (rand() % 20000);
```

The error message I am getting for it says

> error: no match for call to '(std::vector)(unsigned int&)'

Also getting an error on the next line down that says

> error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector::push_back(std::vector&)'

I just need some help trying to figure out how to fix these errors. I've googled the error messages to no real avail.

Comment: Did you mean `temp[l]`, i.e. with square brackets?

Comment: It'd to be `temp[l] = ... ` (square "[]", not round "()" )  And if `vectorList.push_back(temp);` is meant to succeed than it's got to be `vector<vector<int>> vectorList`. And that is, btw, a not-so-mild design catastrophe.

Comment: @decltype_auto I was going to agree with you but on second thought... is it? I mean, resizing the outer vector moves the inner vectors around on the heap, but _their_ elements (the integers) won't be re-allocated, will they?

Comment: Hmmm..  `pow(2,i)` -- `i` is not initialized.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie not to mention overkill for this situation. It suffices to set `int i = 100` and do `i *= 2` inside the `j`-loop. The code is shaky in many respects, I suggest OP post it to Code Review for some helpful tips.

Comment: @CompuChip Once the code is working, then it's a viable question for Code Review, but as it stands, it'd be closed as off-topic there.

Comment: @CompuChip It's not just about relocation, given he ever initializes i (what he should do), that just produces the non-contiguous version of what a flat 1D vector used with sliced access would do more efficiently. And also - the flatter, the more easier it will be to interface with usual math libs which can use a flat field to construct a ND-Array from that.

Comment: @EthanBierlein: This is too trivial for a dedicated code review, but as you mention it - we'd imo really need a reviewed reference implementation of a C++11-version of an ND-array; esp for 2D, because of the frequency of C++ "array[][]"-type questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, an element of a vector is accessed using array-notation, i.e. with square brackets. That means

```
temp(l) = (rand() % 20000);
```

should be

```
temp[l] = (rand() % 20000);
```

Moreover, you say you want a vector of vectors, so you should declare `vectorList` as one:

```
vector<int> vectorList;
```

should be

```
vector<vector<int>> vectorList;
```

The compiler is telling you this: you said that `vectorList` is a vector of `int`s, but if you read the error message carefully it says you are trying to call `push_back` with a `std::vector&`.

Finally, you don't seem to be doing anything with the result... did you mean for your function to return a value?

Comment: All I will be having it do is print out.